# Deleting the same lines from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, computational-geometry

Say I have a list of Lines:

```
lines = {Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {Sqrt[
    5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}}], 
 Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, {0, 1}}], 
 Line[{{0, 1}, {-Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}}], 
 Line[{{-Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, {-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}}], 
 Line[{{-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {Sqrt[
    5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}}], 
 Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {0, 1}}], 
 Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {-Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}}], 
 Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 
    1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}}]}
```

We can see that `lines[[5]]` and `lines[[8]]` are the same:

`lines[[5]]`

> Line[{{-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {Sqrt[
>      5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}}]

`lines[[8]]`

> Line[{{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 
>      1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}}]

I tried to use `Union` and `DeleteDuplicates` to get rid of a duplicate, but none of them worked. Is it because they can't deal with `Line` environment? What are the alternatives?

Comment: they are not the same. There is a minus before `Sqrt`

Comment: the order of the points in each line is different but the points are the same, i.e. the lines are the same

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114046/find-duplicates-in-list-of-infiniteline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[lines, Sort @@ # &]
```

or

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort @@@ lines]
```

The key is to realize that we have to `Apply` `Sort` one level deeper because of the head `Line`.

Comment: I see. Thank you @Henrik !

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use [`RegionEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual):

```
Length @ lines
Length @ DeleteDuplicates[lines, RegionEqual]
```

> 8
>
> 7

If your lines had more than 2 segments, than using  [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort) to canonicalize wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the arguments of the 5-th and 8-th terms go in different order. Indeed, let us take only the arguments:

```
arg = lines[[All, 1]];
```

and let us try to compare the arguments of the 5th and 8th terms:

```
arg[[5]] === arg[[8]]

(*  False  *)
```

Now let us sort the arguments:

```
newArg = Sort /@ lines[[All, 1]]
```

and let us check the 5th and 8th terms

```
newArg[[5]] === newArg[[8]]

(*  True  *)
```

Now the duplicates will be deleted, and here is the result:

```
Line /@ DeleteDuplicates[newArg]
```

Have fun!

Comment: Nice! Thank you!